# Make a SQL Server .bak file protected and known only within my application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, smo

I'm using VB.net 2013 and SQL Server 2008R2.

In my application I have 2 subs: Backup and Restore (created with SMO) that create a backup of database and restore a backup file to SQL Server.

These are working, but I have a problem :

The `.bak` file is not protected, so someone can restore it to a SQL Server even without my program.

Is there anything that I can do when create and restore the `.bak` file in order that :

- The file can be restored only within my application
- When I do a restore, first to check if the selected file is a file that is created within my application, otherwise an error should be displayed and no restore should be made.

Thank you !

Comment: If your aim is to simply prevent mistakes, just 
1. Rename the .bak file to something like .useMyProgram
2. Do not give restore rights to anyone else except the login used by the program

Answer (score 0):

Starting with SQL Server 2014, you can encrypt your backups. And prior to SQL Server 2012, you could protect the media set with a password (but it wasn't really good protection from my understanding). If you're worried about it, you're going to have to write your own backup/restore mechanism. Just make sure you don't miss anything! :)

Comment: And what do you mean about "your own backup/restore mechanism" ?

Comment: Find another way to serialize the database that isn't a `backup database` command.

Comment: I'd also ask what you're trying to protect against? Someone could just create their own database backup that circumvent whatever mechanism you come up with. In short, you're putting effort into something that doesn't afford you the protection you think it does.

Comment: I need to achieve 2 things : 1) I want that if someone take the .bak file , I want to prevent that he can restore the database to another sql server  without my program. 2) When the user try to do a restore inside my application , I want to make my application able to know that the file that is being to restore is not created from inside the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use symmetrical encryption, the password can be easily extracted from you app' binaries. Same is true for any asymmetrical algorithm, since you need both private and public keys in the same place (unless there would be no question).

In short - impossible to do the way you stated it, short of creating your own backup file format. And even if you do, where's the guarantee it will be as reliable and well-tested as that of Microsoft's?

A bit of advise for the future: never cross your way with DBAs, especially corporate ones. The first time your app will fail to restore its backup (or is it absolutely bugless?) or introduce corruption, you might learn about pneuma, soma and sarx a little bit more than you would like it to...

Comment: But after I create the backup , I have a .bak file. Is it possible to do a custom encryption of this file , and to remove encryption before restoring ?

Comment: @alex, sure you can, but everybody else can create a backup of the same database for their own uses, providing they have sufficient permissions. As long it's standard SQL Server, there is no protection from DBA. Maybe you need to rethink what you are protecting and whom you are defending against.

Comment: Let's suppose that I don't have this problem , so users can't create backup's on sql server management. I have only the problem that someone take an already created .bak file from my program. So what can I do to prevent restoring this .bak file to another sql server.